Wordpress | Cpanel | Compress taking long time | huge unwanted file is created
I'm new to WordPress. I have a live website and was attempting to clone it using cPanel. To do this, I decided to back up all the files under the Public_html folder. I selected all the files, right-clicked, and clicked on compress. The destination path was /home/public_html/backup_clone.zip. However, it was taking too long (I waited for 45 minutes) so I closed the browser window. Now, I see a file named "ZikyLnD" with a size of 6 GB under the Public_html folder. I tried again, and the same thing happened; a new file named "ziPnLOsw" with a size of 10 GB was created. I want to delete them to release the space. Can anyone advise me on whether I should delete these files to free up space? I'm concerned it might affect the website.
I really need help.
Thanks

You are making archive of your files and asking should you keep it ? First your website obv is big and you need to wait as much time is needed. Dont stop the proccess. After you have your archive download it or move it to where you want it and delete it from your server after your done. Im not sure what you ask exactly..

Yes, you can safely delete these files as files "ZikyLnD" and "ziPnLOsw" are likely partial or corrupted backups created when the compression process was interrupted. Since they are not complete, they are not useful as backups. These files since were generated during the backup process and are not the part of actual website, so it won't affect the site.

Thank you so much :-) I deleted those files. Once again Thank you Christine.
